# Pdcurses' resize_term seems to work randomly

Tags: c++, curses, pdcurses

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curses.h>
#include "SourceFiles/generalFunc.h"

int main()
{

    initscr();
    int x = resize_term(51, 79);
    sleepMilli(5000); //sleep for 5 seconds
    endwin();
    std::cout << x << " " << int(ERR) << " " << int(OK);

}
```

The screen, on my computer, is not resized in this case, despite the fact that `x` returns back `0` ([indicating the resizing was successful](https://linux.die.net/man/3/resizeterm)). It remains the same size as the original terminal window. However, if I either increase 79 to 80, or decrease 51 to 50, then the screen resizes on my screen like normal. My screen is big enough to accomodate these sizes by a mile - even still, changing from 80 to 79 is a DECREASE in window size yet for some reason it does not work. It seems like it doesn't like going below a certain aspect ratio.

Is there any more information as to why there seems to be a limit on the resizing I can do even if these numbers are nowhere near the limit my screen can hold? This is pdcurses on 64 bit Windows.

Comment: If you are on Win64, why not use the standard console functions instead of some unix-port thing?

Answer (score 3):

`resize_term` is an ncurses function.

The [`resize_term`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/resizeterm.3x.html#h3-resize_term) function does not change your *terminal's* size; it changes the size which *ncurses assumes*.

Since nothing is displayed by curses, and (see [notes in the manual page](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/resizeterm.3x.html#h2-NOTES)), your example does no [`getch`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Reading-characters), there's nothing to show by curses as a change.

Interestingly, PDCurses implemented a function with the same name (inspired by ncurses: there are several of these) which is described differently.  Quoting from the comments in `pdcurses/initscr.c`:

```
    resize_term() is effectively two functions: When called with  
    nonzero values for nlines and ncols, it attempts to resize the  
    screen to the given size. When called with (0, 0), it merely  
    adjusts the internal structures to match the current size after  
    the screen is resized by the user. On the currently supported  
    platforms, this functionality is mutually exclusive: X11 allows  
    user resizing, while DOS, OS/2 and Win32 allow programmatic  
    resizing. If you want to support user resizing, you should check  
    for getch() returning KEY_RESIZE, and/or call is_termresized()  
    at appropriate times; if either condition occurs, call  
    resize_term(0, 0). Then, with either user or programmatic  
    resizing, you'll have to resize any windows you've created, as  
    appropriate; resize_term() only handles stdscr and curscr.
```

and the function begins with this:

```
int resize_term(int nlines, int ncols)
{   
    PDC_LOG(("resize_term() - called: nlines %d\n", nlines));

    if (!stdscr || PDC_resize_screen(nlines, ncols) == ERR)
        return ERR;

    SP->lines = PDC_get_rows();
    LINES = SP->lines - SP->linesrippedoff - SP->slklines;
    SP->cols = COLS = PDC_get_columns();
```

which in turn calls this for Windows console:

```
int PDC_resize_screen(int nlines, int ncols)
{
    SMALL_RECT rect;
    COORD size, max;

    if (nlines < 2 || ncols < 2)
        return ERR;

    max = GetLargestConsoleWindowSize(pdc_con_out);

    rect.Left = rect.Top = 0;
    rect.Right = ncols - 1;

    if (rect.Right > max.X)
        rect.Right = max.X;

    rect.Bottom = nlines - 1;

    if (rect.Bottom > max.Y)
        rect.Bottom = max.Y;

    size.X = rect.Right + 1;
    size.Y = rect.Bottom + 1;

    _fit_console_window(pdc_con_out, &rect);
    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(pdc_con_out, size);
    _fit_console_window(pdc_con_out, &rect);
    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(pdc_con_out, size);
    SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(pdc_con_out);

    return OK;
}
```

so that you can see the result is an incompatible function.  (There is a port to SDL which is similar).  There are a few questions related to PDCurses behavior:

- [PDCurses resize_term arbitrarily fails or succeeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364041/pdcurses-resize-term-arbitrarily-fails-or-succeeds)
- [Method to tell PDCurses to make the window the same size as the physical screen programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18818600/method-to-tell-pdcurses-to-make-the-window-the-same-size-as-the-physical-screen)

However, PDCurses usually installs its header file as **`<xcurses.h>`** to denote its differences from curses (or ncurses).  I assumed that the question was about ncurses, and the problem is confusion about what the library function does:

- [Resize terminal and scrolling problem with ncurses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738803/resize-terminal-and-scrolling-problem-with-ncurses)

Back to PDCurses, it is odd that it makes the same two calls *twice*.  The PDCurses function makes possibly several tries, reducing the given values until they fit - or not:

```
 /* Calls SetConsoleWindowInfo with the given parameters, but fits them  
    if a scoll bar shrinks the maximum possible value. The rectangle  
    must at least fit in a half-sized window. */

static BOOL _fit_console_window(HANDLE con_out, CONST SMALL_RECT *rect)
{   
    SMALL_RECT run;
    SHORT mx, my;

    if (SetConsoleWindowInfo(con_out, TRUE, rect))
        return TRUE;

    run = *rect;
    run.Right /= 2;
    run.Bottom /= 2;

    mx = run.Right;
    my = run.Bottom;

    if (!SetConsoleWindowInfo(con_out, TRUE, &run))
        return FALSE;

    for (run.Right = rect->Right; run.Right >= mx; run.Right--)
        if (SetConsoleWindowInfo(con_out, TRUE, &run))
            break;

    if (run.Right < mx)
        return FALSE;

    for (run.Bottom = rect->Bottom; run.Bottom >= my; run.Bottom--)
        if (SetConsoleWindowInfo(con_out, TRUE, &run))
            return TRUE;

    return FALSE;
}
```

The code looks ... odd, besides doing the same thing twice.  Referring to the MSDN description of [SetConsoleWindowInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686125%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the rectangle parameter is an *in* parameter (not modified).  Following the parameters through, it's taking the requested size, and trying in succession to

1. set the requested size, or
2. set the requested lines while reducing columns down to half the initial size, or
3. set the requested columns while reducing lines down to half the initial size.

Perhaps the reason it does this twice is because there is some indeterminate behavior in the console API.  The comments in the code offer no help.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. The question is about PDcurses on 64-bit Windows. I'll edit my OP.